# Display Alseye M120 Plus temperature on the command line

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

I'm newbie in this forum, although I've been using Linux flavors longer than a decade now.

I have decided to give a fresh looking to my hardware and got an RGB CPU fan which has a little screen to display the temperature, nothing more, it is *[*Alseye** brand, model **M120 Plus**](https://www.alseyecorp.com/product-item/m120d-plus/), got it from Amazon.

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS**

**My motherboard is a microATX Gigabyte B460M Aorus Pro** (it has built-in temperature sensors).

The thing is that **the RGB works well with OpenRGB** **but the temperature displays 24C all the time**, and this must be malfunctioning for sure since the fans actually speed faster as the CPU gets loaded with work, which means the temperature should oscillate (no CPU fan can work that perfect to keep the temperature still).

Does anyone know how to get it displayed right?

Comment: contact the manufacturer.  I'm not sure how anything in Ubuntu would change what is displayed on this hardware.  You could run `sensors` in Ubuntu to see the temps (may need to be configured).

Comment: I was thinking of unofficial driver or software similar to OpenRGB or some tweak in the OS detecting the fan first and then get it display the right temp, but definitely don't know how to do that

Comment: How?  I'm going by the manual for this...  It has 2 ARGB connectors which controls the LEDs.  It has a single PWM fan connector for 2 fans, not sure if you can even get fan speeds with 2 hooked on one but it might work.  Then there is the SATA power connector to power it.  There is no communication cable for Ubuntu to do anything.

Comment: There might be a way since OpenRGB lets me set up the RGB for that fan

Comment: @ubuntero I have not been able to connect this fan to OpenRGB. Are you connecting through an Asus motherboard?